# The Oregon Trail Card Game: can I talk about my supply cards?

Tags: the-oregon-trail-card-game

Players are dealt supply cards in the game to help get rid of "calamities".

The rules state this about Supply Cards:

> **7:** Players should look at their own Supply Cards, then place them face down on the table. Players may look at their own Supply Cards at any time.

This does not specify whether or not players may tell other players what they have. I could see where some player may ask the table if someone has for example, a `Medicine`, and another player may have it but choose to **not** to tell you. Is the "card's not displayed to other players" rule an effort to stop players from coercing other players into playing specific cards?

Or does this rule hint that players may not talk about what Supply Cards they have at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the SAMPLE PLAY section it says:

> Bob says, "I have a **Clothes Card** I can spare for you."

This hints that you can share information about what cards you have before you play them. Frankly I don't see how it is winnable without some supply card teamwork.